# Directory of pybind11 module

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am writing a python module, that is going to be a library, using pybind11.

At some point in my C++ code, I need to know the absolute path of my .so/.dll module (I need that to access to some files in a subdirectory inside the package containing my module).
I tried to access to the `__file__` attribute in this way:

```
namespace py = pybind11;

std::string path;

std::string getPath() {
   return path;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m) {
    path = m.attr("__file__").cast<std::string>();
    //use path in some way to figure out the path the module...


    m.def("get_path", &getPath);
}
```

but I get the error

```
ImportError: AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute '__file__'
```

Is there any way to know the absolute path of a module written with pybind11?

Comment: From my understanding, `__file__` is set by python when you call `import`. Makes sense because where python finds that module can be highly variable based on the python path. So if you're running this code in c++, you're going to need to rely on some sort of c++ methodology for figuring out where the module is located. `std::filesystem::current_path` might be an option if you in c++17 and your library is in the same folder as your executable

Comment: The problem here is that there is no executable, because this module is going to be part of a python library. The user can place the package containing my module wherever he wants.
I tried with [QDir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html), but what it returns is the path where python is called, which is not the path where my module is placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running solely from C++, this should work assuming your module is named `example` and can be found on the pythonpath.

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;


void getModulePath()
{
  py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
  py::object example = py::module::import("example");
  return example.attr("__file__").cast<std::string>();
}
```

If your application is running from inside python I think the following should work

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;


void getModulePath()
{
  py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
  py::object example = py::module::import("example");
  return example.attr("__file__").cast<std::string>();
}
```

This works because we are using the python interpreter to import the example module so the `__file__` attribute will get set

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!